# Android in-app billing error: Authentication is required

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I have an app published on Google Play Store with an in-app purchase to upgrade to the full version.
The IAB library was updated to V3 in the latest app release.

Many users complain that they can't buy the upgrade. The error is:
"Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account."

[image: screenshot]

I also noticed this error in the logs:
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/preparePurchase

This is a managed product.
I've checked SKU, keys, everything, but couldn't find the cause of this error. My users are complaining and I'm losing income... Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: This error occurs when Google can't find the ITEM SKU (product ID) or when the ITEM is not active (when you save you need activate it).

Also, the next time use a BETA CHANNEL and a test account (use now and test in some users).

Comment: @Santiago The SKU exists and is active. I also used the Beta channel, with same error...

Comment: @Patrick have you found what was wrong about this?

Comment: hi did you find a solution I have the same problem?